# WordPress theme builder elementor shows changes happening but cant see them live

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

i was over on a clients website, editing with elementor and then all of a sudden i couldn't see the changes live which i made on elementor. i tried clearing the cache of browser and wordrpress as well.
If somebody knows how to fix this please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always check in incognito mode before doing anything to fix the problem.

And you can also just "Regenerate Files & Data" and "sync library" from elementor > tools

And if still, you can't see the changes then try with safe mode.